# Can MSAccess Forms be Updated Via QUERY?

Tags: insert, ms-access-2007

I'm assuming the answer after basic searching is no. But here's the situation at a high level. I have a legacy access database that stores config data in forms. In the past we've always manually updated this config data, but msaccess dbs aren't exactly source control friendly. Is there a way to essentially run an insert statement to add a record to a form? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: It has a record source. We'll just call it CONFIG for the purpose of this discussion.

Comment: OK, then if CONFIG is a table, you can use a query to update the data that table contains.  Can that work for you?

Comment: CONFIG is not actually a table, though; Maybe, that's a longer term solution. Is there a way to preserve form data if you create such a table?

Comment: It might help if you were to [edit] your question and explain what you mean when you say that the application "stores config data in forms". Stores it how? Hard-coded values in Class Module code? `.Value` properties of (possibly hidden) controls on the form? ...? Also, if the record source is "not actually a table" then what is it?